# python timestamp result in the form of microseconds "41850.0743055556"

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get the timestamp from website in form of "03/24/2014 19:30" as part of my crawling content, the related partial code is as following:

```
import parsedatetime as pdt
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

PostTime ="Thursday" 
cal = pdt.Calendar()
ParseTime = cal.parse(PostTime)[0]
Timeresult = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(ParseTime))
print Timeresult
```

The code works fine when I try it on sample webpages. The result is in the form of "03/24/2014 19:30". However, when I actually use this code to retrieve data from the website. One file get the right results, another file get the timestamp in the form of microseconds "41850.0743055556". I used exactly the same code in both files. 
Can anybody help me understand why this happened? Thanks very much.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Sure, for the first 7 weeks of creation we had Tursday, then it was changed by committee to Thursday. Since his time is only 11.6 days after the epoch, it makes total sense. :)

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks. Sorry for the typo. I just assign "Thursday" to PostTime as an example, in the complete code the value of PostTime is crawling from the webpage, it can be any day from Monday to Sunday, or in the form of "10 hours ago" or in the from of " August 1st, 2014".

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're trying to do. You go from a string, to a `struct_time`, to a UNIX timestamp, to datetime object. What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: @NickODell Thank you very much for your reply. I need the datetime object. The original time I got from the website in different format. It uses the string like "July 26th, 2014" for older items, and uses relative time such as Monday, yesterday, and 18 hours ago for newer items. I need change all of them to a date object. I am sorry maybe I handle it in a wrong way. I am a new programmer, just starting learning programming. Thank you very much for your patient. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Sure. I tried running the code you posted. I can't reproduce the output you're getting. I always get something in the form '2014-08-14 21:03:25'

Comment: hi, could you locate the problem? i.e. what input string produced the wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misread and didn't see the part about relative dates being an option as well.

Use conditional logic and timedetla to parse relative dates and use dateutil to parse others

Here's a basic example:
    from datetime import timedelta
    from dateutil import parser

```
def parse_relative(s):
    """ This assumes relative dates are in the formatin XX hours ago

        Returns None if s cannot be parsed.
    """

    if s in ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']:
        return parser.parse(s) - timedelta(weeks=1)
    if 'day' in s:
        return datetime.now() - timedelta(days=int(s.split()[0]))
    if 'hour' in s:
        return datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=int(s.split()[0]))
    if 'minute' in s:
        return datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=int(s.split()[0]))
    if 'second' in s:
        return datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=int(s.split()[0]))

    # if not days/hours/minutes/seconds assume its not a relative date and try and
    # try to parse with dateutil
    try:
        return parser.parse(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Example output:

```
In [45]: parse_relative('1 hour ago')
Out[45]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 12, 10, 55, 54, 950704)

In [46]: parse_relative('13 hours ago')
Out[46]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 11, 22, 56, 1, 606846)

In [47]: parse_relative('13 seconds ago')
Out[47]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 12, 11, 56, 8, 503996)

In [48]: parse_relative('13 minutes ago')
Out[48]: datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 12, 11, 43, 29, 390428)

In [49]: parse_relative('03/24/2014 19:30')
Out[49]: datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 24, 19, 30)

In [50]: parse_relative('03/24/2014 19:30:13')
Out[50]: datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 24, 19, 30, 13)
```

Note that this is a naive implementation that assumes that relative dates will always be 'XX *time unit* ago*  You'd have to add extra logic for week or year and also for relative dates in the future.

Comment: He mentioned input string could be relative time, as "Monday, yesterday, and 18 hours ago"

Comment: @jay3686 Thanks for the help. The website uses "Monday, Tuesday,..." to represent the items actived within the past 7 days. Can you please also give me some suggestion or solution on how to deal with this kind of date values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sure,  by default dateutil will parse Monday, Tuesday, ..., but it will be the coming day. Friday would parse as 8/15/2014.  If you want it to be the previous week, you need to special case those strings and subtract a week with time delta.  I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Also keep in mind that 'dateutil.parser.parse('Friday')'
will return 'datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 0, 0)'  (The time portion is dropped)